# Connect graphaware neo4j-reco to standalone neo4j server

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, recommendation-engine, graphaware

I want to run [neo4j-reco](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-reco) README exmple with standalone server.

How can I change it to use and connect to my external neo4j server?

Comment: Change the ip address in the configuration? Or Add more information.

Comment: I couldn't find this config property. what is the property name? I have a neo4j instance that accesable in localhost:7474/browser. I want to make recommendation engine for this instance but this example use embedded server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy the recommendation engine jar as well as the corresponding version to your neo4j standalone server.

Then you can create a stored procedure attached to the engine so you can request recommendations via Cypher.

There is an example of the procedure here :

https://github.com/graphaware/recommendations-meetup/blob/master/src/main/java/com/graphaware/meetup/procedure/MeetupRecommendationProcedure.java

And the corresponding integration test :

https://github.com/graphaware/recommendations-meetup/blob/master/src/test/java/com/graphaware/meetup/MyRecommendationEngineIntegrationTest.java#L72

Comment: Thanks, it's good. Also below link was very helpful: https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-template